# Dropdownlist onchange action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In my view there is this `DropDownList`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("fOrderstatus", TryCast( ViewBag.StatusOptions, SelectList), "--pick--",  New With { .title="Pick an orderstatus"} )
```

The view shows purchaseorders and the dropdownlist should give the user the possibility to filter, e.g. choosing only 'active' orders.

I prefer a solution in plain vanilla ASP.NET MVC.

In old skool ASP classic I would have an `onchange=submit` in the SELECT and in the called ASP (via the FORM action) a `Request.Form([name of the SELECT])`...

Comment: i really searched endless for my answer, and maybe my last remark did it: found the answer myzelf. First you need to define the FORM:
 

    @Using Html.BeginForm("index",  "purchaseorders")
    
        @Html.DropDownList("fOrderstatus", TryCast( ViewBag.StatusOptions, SelectList), "--pick--",  New With { .title="Pick an orderstatus", .onchange="submit();"} )
        
    End Using


In the controller you receive the selected option:

     Function Index(ByVal fOrderstatus As String) As ViewResult

Comment: If you have found the answer that is great, but instead of a comment create a proper answer and accept it. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i really searched endless for my answer, and maybe my last remark did it: found the answer myzelf. First you need to define the FORM:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("index",  "purchaseorders")

    @Html.DropDownList("fOrderstatus", TryCast( ViewBag.StatusOptions, SelectList), "--pick--",  New With { .title="Pick an orderstatus", .onchange="submit();"} )

End Using
```

In the controller you receive the selected option:

```
 Function Index(ByVal fOrderstatus As String) As ViewResult
```